# Devo adicionar o arquivo .suo ao meu source control?

Tags: visual-studio, versionamento

O Visual Studio possui um arquivo com a extensão `.suo` que grava algumas opções do projeto. Pra que serve esse arquivo e quais opções ele armazena?

Esse arquivo deve ser adicionado ao projeto no TFS, SVN ou qualquer outro *source control* que esteja sendo utilizado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este arquivo guarda as configurações e preferências que são definidas **por usuário** no Visual Studio.

Sobre enviá-los para um SCM: depende da sua intenção.

Se estiver num projeto sozinho e quiser manter este arquivo no controle de versões para manter as configurações iguais em dois ambientes distintos, me parece normal. Se estiver num projeto com outras pessoas programando junto, isto já não parece uma boa ideia.

Basicamente, é isso: mantenha o arquivo no *source control* se for um projeto individual (ou se quiser forçar os colaboradores do projeto a seguir suas configurações do Visual Studio). Caso contrário, mantenha estes arquivos ignorados.